# paginar los registros de un foreach en PHP parametrado por un select

Tags: php, paginación

Estoy realizando una consulta a una tabla donde tomo un parámetro desde un SELECT y envío el resultado a un array para mostrarlo en pantalla. Dada la cantidad de registros, lo quiero paginar. Cuando realizo la paginación si hay 100 registro que divido a 20 por página, muestra los primeros 20 pero luego muestra 75 resultados en general sin que se cumpla el criterio enviado desde el SELECT. Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

Este es mi código:

```
   <?php
         if (isset($_GET["id_gal"])){

            $reg_x_pag = 20;

            $sql_page="SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE id_gal = $id_ga";

            $resultado_page=$base->prepare($sql_page);

            $resultado_page->execute(array());                        

            $nro_reg=$resultado_page->rowCount();

            $nro_pag = ceil($nro_reg/$reg_x_pag);

            if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $page = 1;
            } else {
                $page = $_GET['page'];
            }
            $prime_pag = ($page-1)*$reg_x_pag;

            $registro1=$base->query('SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE id_gal = ' . $id_ga . ' ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT ' . $prime_pag . ',' .  $reg_x_pag)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
          ?>            
        <div class="fr-row-padding">      
            <?php foreach($registro1 as $art_1): ?> 
            <div class="fr-col l3 m6 fr-margin-bottom">
              <div class="fr-display-container">
                <div class="fr-center fr-color fr-height5 fr-padding"><?php echo $art_1->nombre?></div>
                <a href="#" class="circ  fa fa-search-plus dos"></a>
                <img class="zoom" src="/images/articulos/<?php echo $art_1->img ?>" alt="Capricho&acute;s" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="fr-color2 fr-padding">
                    <p>
                        <span class="fr-xlarge fr-padding-right">&euro;<?php echo $art_1->precio?></span>
                        <?php 
                        if ($precioA!=0){?>
                        <span class="fr-xlarge tachartexto">&euro;<?php echo $art_1->precioA?></span>
                        <?php }?>
                        <a href="V1.8/artV1.8sel.php?Id=<?php echo $art_1->id_pro?>" class="fr-right fr-xlarge">Ver...</a>
                    </p>   
                </div>                          
              </div>

            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="fr-col s12 fr-margin-bottom fr-center paginacion">
            <?php     
            for ($page=1;$page<=$nro_pag;$page++) {
                        echo '<a href="catV1.8pro.php?page='. $page .'">' . $page . '</a> ';
                    }
            ?>
            </div>                        
        </div>
            <? 
            }else{
            ?>
            <div class="fr-row-padding" >

            <?php 
            $registro=$base->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE ver_pag = 'on' AND precio <> '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,20")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);                        
            foreach($registro as $art): ?>
            <?php $titulo=$art->nombre;
                  $precio=$art->precio;
                  $precioA=$art->precioA;
                  $img=$art->img;
                  $diapo_a=$art->diapo1;
                  $diapo_b=$art->diapo2;
                  $descripcion=$art->descripcion;
                  $id_pro=$art->id_pro;
            ?>
            <div class="fr-col l3 m6 fr-margin-bottom">
              <div class="fr-display-container">
                <div class="fr-center fr-color fr-height5 fr-padding"><?=$titulo?></div>
                <a href="#" class="circ  fa fa-search-plus dos"></a>
                <img class="zoom" src="/images/articulos/<?=$img?>" alt="Capricho&acute;s" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="fr-color2 fr-padding">
                    <p>
                        <span class="fr-xlarge fr-padding-right">&euro;<?=$precio?></span>
                        <?php 
                        if ($precioA!=0){?>
                        <span class="fr-xlarge tachartexto">&euro;<?=$precioA?></span>
                        <?php }?>
                        <a href="V1.8/artV1.8sel.php?Id=<?php echo $id_pro?>" class="fr-right fr-xlarge">Ver...</a>
                    </p>   
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
            <?
            }
            ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Este código es vulnerable a ataques de cross site scripting (XSS) y (parece que) también a inyección SQL y no debería usarse en un entorno de cara al público debido a los problemas de seguridad que presenta. Lee más sobre XSS e inyección SQL (hay varias preguntas en este sitio con buenas respuestas) y corrige esas vulnerabilidades.

Comment: Gracias Álvaro Montoro, por tu recomendación y tiempo para responderme. Pero con respecto a mi pregunta me podrías sugerir algo. Me pondré con lo de XSS. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: La pongo como favorita para echarle un ojo luego. No tendré un ordenador a mano hasta dentro de un buen rato.